# HammerJS implement gesture hold and tap

Tags: javascript, multi-touch, hammer.js

I'm a newbie with HammerJS. So, I have no idea how to implement the following gesture:

> I want to select an element with hold. While holding one finger on the
>   element, another finger taps anywhere on the screen. On the end of the
>   tap, an action starts.

Is it possible to wait for a tap while holding the element?

Comment: Maybe you could listen for both the hold *and* tap gestures, and check if the user is also holding inside the touch callback?

Comment: How can I listen for both gestures? Using a global variable who is 1 if the user holds an element? And inside the touch function, I look if this variable is 1 oder 0 ?

Comment: You should be able to listen to separate events firing different callbacks (example using jQuery): `$element.on('tap', callback)` and `$element.on('hold', otherCallback)`. (make sure to use the right HammerJS event names, I'm guessing them)